# Must there be some (a,b): p \divides q^a-r^b, where p,q, and r are distinct primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p, q, r$ be distinct primes and $a,b$ be natural numbers greater than $1$. Is it necessarily the case that for all $p,q,r$ there exists some $a,b: p \mid{(q^a - r^b)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $q^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $r^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$, so $p \mid (q^{p-1} - r^{p-1})$.

If $p=2$, then $q$ and $r$ must be odd, so $q^2$ and $r^2$ are still odd, so $p \mid (q^2 - r^2)$. (This is done so that $a, b > 1$ as required.)

Comment: A little extra explanation for the case $p=2$ would perfect your Answer (since we require $a,b\gt 1$).

Comment: done, thanks.$ $